# Best way to pass environment variables file to GCP instance startup script

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables

I have an environment variable file that I need to add to my app directory when my app starts up. I can't check it into source control for obvious reasons, what is the best way to pass this file (or the secrets themselves) to my app on startup?

Right now I have a load balancer connected to an instance group and when a new instance boots up it follows a startup script, I can't figure out how to pass my secrets in via the startup script.

Answer (score 0):

To pass an environment variables file to a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) instance startup script, you can use the --metadata flag with the gcloud compute instances create command. The metadata flag allows you to pass key-value pairs to the instance, and you can use the key startup-script-url to specify a URL for your startup script file. In your startup script, you can then source the environment variables file and use the exported variables.